# Why does directoryExists test true but cfdirectory fails?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a page that accesses in-memory files. We have 10 - 20k files stored in hundreds  of directories (up to 2000). All directories and files are created programmatically. There are no permissions set or changed. All files use the default CF account, which we have had no issues with.

Every once in a while, we get an error. We test for the existence of a directory. If it exists, we get the contents of the directory and do something with the files. We are successfully able to read directories whether there is content or not.

```
<cfscript>
    LOCAL.RamFileDir = "ram://CatSearchMenu/9160";
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>
<cfif directoryExists("#LOCAL.RamFileDir#") eq true>
    #LOCAL.RamFileDir# exists<br>
    <cfdirectory name="getRamFiles" directory="#LOCAL.RamFileDir#" action="list">
    <cfdump var="#getRamFiles#">
<cfelse>
    #LOCAL.RamFileDir# DOES NOT exist<br>
</cfif>     
</cfoutput>
```

Here's the error I am getting...

```
An error occurred when performing a file operation listFiles on file /CatSearchMenuSubCats/9160.

The cause of this exception was: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not list the contents of folder "ram:///CatSearchMenuSubCats/9160"..

The error occurred in E:/INETPUB/WWWROOT/AVCATALOGS/...: line 92

 91 :                   <!--- GET THE FILES --->
 92 :                   <cfdirectory name="getRamFiles" 
 93 :                       directory="#LOCAL.RamFileDir#" 
 94 :                       action="list">
```

The getFileInfo() function shows that there's nothing preventing me from accessing the directory.

The image below shows a slightly different path. The path is different for the sake of brevity.

[image]

**EXTRA BOUNTY INFO ~ added 6/9/2014**

This specific directory passes the directoryExists() test but when we use cfdirectory to list the contents, it chokes. How could it pass one test and then fail?

We cannot do any cfdirectory action on this directory, no create, delete, or list action will work. We can, however, access the files within the directory if we know the name of the file.

When we restart the ColdFusion services, the ram is wiped out. Automatically, the files are created as needed by another process. The files can be up and running and working fine for days on end. Then, suddenly, just ONE of the directories is not available. It's never the same directory. A few days later, ONE MORE directory becomes unavailable. Again, every other directory (of the two thousand) works perfectly. Again, all of the files within any directory is perfectly accessible. Once a directory becomes unavailable, it remains that way until we restart the ColdFusion services.

```
<cfscript>
// SET RAM FILE BASE
LOCAL.RamFileBase = "ram://includes";
</cfscript>

<!--- TEST THE BASE --->
<cfoutput>
<cfif directoryExists("#LOCAL.RamFileBase#") eq true>
<h1>#LOCAL.RamFileBase# BASE EXISTS</h1>

<!--- GET THE BASE --->
<cfdirectory name="getRamBase" directory="#LOCAL.RamFileBase#" action="list">

<!--- LOOP THROUGH THE BASE --->        
<cfloop query="getRamBase">

    <!--- TEST THE SUB DIRECTORY --->
    <cfif directoryExists("#LOCAL.RamFileBase#/#getRamBase.Name#") eq true>
        <h3>#LOCAL.RamFileBase#/#getRamBase.Name# SUB DIR EXISTS</h3>

        <!--- GET THE SUB DIRECTORY --->
        <cfdirectory name="getRamSubDir" directory="#LOCAL.RamFileBase#/#getRamBase.Name#" action="list">

        <!--- LOOP THROUGH THE SUB DIRECTORY --->
        <cfloop query="getRamSubDir">

            <!--- TEST THE SUB SUB DIRECTORY ~ WHERE THE FILES ARE --->
            <cfif directoryExists("#LOCAL.RamFileBase#/#getRamBase.Name#/#getRamSubDir.Name#") eq true>
                <b>#LOCAL.RamFileBase#/#getRamBase.Name#/#getRamSubDir.Name#</b> SUB SUB DIR EXISTS<br>

                <!--- GET THE FILES IN THE SUB SUB DIRECTORY --->
                                    <!--- THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS --->
                <cfdirectory name="getRamFiles" 
                        directory="#LOCAL.RamFileBase#/#getRamBase.Name#/#getRamSubDir.Name#" 
                        action="list" 
                        sort="DateLastModified ASC">

                    <!--- LOOP THROUGH THE FILES --->
                    <cfloop query="getRamFiles">
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't have permission to read the directory's contents?  You may want to use the `canRead` property returned by the getFileInfo metadata, see http://www.sagarganatra.com/2012/01/coldfusion-tip-how-to-tell-if-path-is.html

Comment: PS you can write `<cfif directoryExists("#LOCAL.RamFileDir#") eq true>` as simply `<cfif directoryExists(LOCAL.RamFileDir)>`

Comment: Duncan, yes, I can drop the "eq true" as well as the pound signs. Are you thinking that this is the issue?

Comment: No, I think it's due to a permissions problem

Comment: Is the directory empty? I see it has a size of 0 (from your dump). Does `cfdirectory` have a problem listing on an empty directory?

Comment: The directory is empty. I am successfully able to read the contents of many other empty directories.

Comment: Okay, was just asking as I couldn't recall off the top-of-my-head. I don't see anything wrong with your code. ???

Comment: Could you share a bit more of the exception?

Comment: wait... read the exception. am i missing something? it seems to be pointing at a different location. `ram:///CatSearchMenuSubCats/9160` vs `ram:///includes/CatSearchMenuSubCats/9160` from the dump. Just an inconsistency in question?

Comment: Kevin, I abbreviate the code to make it easier to read.

Comment: Could you be exceeding the max number of open files for the OS?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdfaxaay%28vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Is there anything in my code that suggests there are too many files open?

Comment: @EvikJames You are running coldfusion on Apache on what OS server?  Its not Windows, right?  Could it be OS X or Linux?  Next question you say there is a lot of directory and files.  Does the ramdisk have a log file (like maybe some utilities on the drive tha tcan shed light)?  See if there is something going on with the actual disk. I was thinking that maybe it was hibernating or something you you might be catching it when it spins up.  I was also thinking that you were running into a space limitation. I'll wait to hear your comments on these things.

Comment: It's CF 10 on Windows, IIS 7.5. This disk is constantly in use 24/7/365. There is no space limitation. We have the virtual file system max set to 500 MB. I am using about 10 MB. I followed a Ben Nadel tutorial (http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1650-learning-coldfusion-9-the-virtual-file-system-ram-disk.htm) on how to use the RAM Disk. It works wonderfully, with the exception that has become this post.

Comment: Another few questions:  is this a virtual disk (a scratch disk)? You restart and this is wiped correct? And you are using this as a temporary spot to hold your images before you move them to somewhere more important? Is it internal or external to your server? I'm assuming internal?

Comment: I am using the ColdFusion virtual file system. If we restart the server or the ColdFusion service, the files are completely wiped out. The files that are being "held" are htm files. There are no images being used in the virtual file system.

Comment: Can it be due to `Memory Limit for In-Memory Virtual File System` exceeding the permissible limit after a number of days? Are the files created at a specific interval or the number/size of files and directories are fixed?

Comment: The total size of 10,000 files is about 10 MB. We have the max set to 500 MB. The files are created as needed. They process above finds old files and attempts to delete them. I am totally aware of what happens when the max is exceeded. The process still works, but all new files are saved with no content, which is a problem. No errors will be displayed when the max is exceeded.

Comment: Could another process be deleting/modifying the file while this process is running? You have not shared the code that deletes the file. Is that process running inline with this code or are you spawning another thread that is processing parallel to this one? I would assume that ColdFusion also has some built-in functionality to handle the RAM file system. If it reaches the max size allocated it may be attempting to clean older files itself and that process is colliding with your process to do the same.

Comment: This IS the process that runs that deletes the the files. I have not included that code because it's irrelevant. It's irrelevant because the error occurs before the delete. I need to see what's in the directory using cfdirectory before I delete any files.

Comment: This is YOUR process that deletes the files. What I am trying to determine is if there is some other process deleting the files before yours (or somehow locking the files) and thus causes your process to error. If on one line of code the file/directory exists then subsequently it does not that tells me something else is mucking with the file/directory. Step back from your code and think about other things that may be happening concurrently.

Comment: I asked about seeing the deletion code because I cannot tell if you are spawning another thread for the delete (or something similar). The threads could run concurrently and be causing you issues. Another possibility could be that you are kicking this process off via the scheduler and jobs are over-lapping (another being started before the previous finished). I only know what you have shared here and don't know your entire process.

Comment: The process takes about three seconds to run. We schedule it to run hourly. The code above will throw an error on request, just by accessing the URL. I am not spawning another thread.

Comment: I have this EXACT same problem, but ONLY occurs on my root folder.. eg: `ram://production/` and throse and error when i try to do `files = directoryList("ram://production/", true);` if i dump the contents of a folder below this level it works. If i try to read this directory i get `The cause of this exception was: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not list the contents of folder "ram:///production"` anyone have any luck fixing this weird issue?? CF11 update 2

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations and bad Adobe documentation:

Using the `LOCAL` scope is probably OK but I'd prefer you not since the code is not within a function.

While browsing the Adobe docs, I noticed frequent use of 3 forward slashes when referring to in-memory files. ex: `ram:///` Not using 3 may be a subtle issue.

According to http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0-70e2363b121825b20e7-8000.html , the `<cfdirectory />` tag does not appear in the "the following tags are supported for in-memory files:" section. This is troubling since an example just above that section on the same page IS using `<cfdirectory />`

Finally, I don't believe in-memory functionality was meant to deal with 10-20k files stored in hundreds of directories. :) A traditional file system, outside the web root, using proper locking, may be a better option.

Comment: 1) Yes, there are more appropriate scopes to use here. This scope was a holdover from when it was in a function. 2) Yes, the Adbode docs are inconsistent with their use of 2 or 3 slashes. It seems to make no difference at all which one is used. 3) The CFDIRECTORY tag works just fine, no matter what the docs say is supported. 4) What makes you think that the functionality was not mean to support the number of files and folders I am using? Is that just a guess or do you have any evidence?

Comment: The Adobe documentation states that 'in-memory' files are stored in RAM. While the docs do not say "don't store 20k files in hundreds of directories" within RAM, a mental red flag yet appears. 

If you have enough RAM, your JVM is properly tuned, your application server does not encounter significant load, and you've no need to load-balance, then I suppose there's no reason not to continue in your implementation. However, you appear to be encountering subtle errors, hence this question. Good luck :)

Comment: There is ample RAM available and the JVM is properly tuned. The error can occur whether there is 100 or 100,000 files. The server may be up and running for weeks with absolutely no issue and then the error occurs. It seems that the folder becomes corrupt yet the files within the folder is completely accessible. It's baffling.